# How setup AutoPoco to generate collection which is member of entity?

Tags: c#, autopoco

I work on helper application which will generate sample data to my database. I decided to use `AutoPoco` but there is a problem when I setup `AutoPocoContainer` to populate collection.

### Entities

My entities are used in **NHibernate**

```
 public partial class Project
 {
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual System.DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }

    private IList<ProjectMember> _projectMembers = new List<ProjectMember>();

    public virtual IList<ProjectMember> ProjectMembers
    {
      get { return _projectMembers; }
      set { _projectMembers = value; }
    }
}

public partial class ProjectMember
{
    public virtual bool isConfirmed { get; set; }
    public virtual string ProjectPosition { get; set; }
    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
}
```

### Configuration

Here is part of my configuration (only `Project` and `ProjectMember`):

```
IGenerationSessionFactory pocoFactory = AutoPocoContainer.Configure(x =>
{
    x.Conventions(c => c.UseDefaultConventions());
    x.AddFromAssemblyContainingType<CDSUser>();

    // ...
    x.Include<Project>()
        .Setup(c => c.Title).Use<ProjectTitleSource>()
        .Setup(c => c.CreatedAt).Use<DateTimeSource>(new DateTime(2015, 2, 1), new DateTime(2015, 6, 30))
        // here is problem
        .Setup(c => c.ProjectMembers).Collection(1, 10) // if I remove this line everything works
        .Setup(c => c.Description).Use<LoremIpsumSource>();
    x.Include<ProjectMember>()
        .Setup(c => c.isConfirmed).Value(true)
        .Setup(c => c.ProjectPosition).Value(string.Empty)
        .Setup(c => c.Project).FromParent();

    // ...
});
```

Here is step when I try to generate projects:

```
var projects = fixture.List<Project>(100).Get();
```

Everything compiles.

### Error

When I run this then Exception is thrown:

```
System.MissingMethodException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233069
  Message=Cannot create an instance of an interface.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
       at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
       at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
       at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
       at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
       at AutoPoco.DataSources.FlexibleEnumerableSource`3.AutoPoco.Engine.IDatasource.Next(IGenerationContext context)
       at AutoPoco.Engine.ObjectPropertySetFromSourceAction.Enact(IGenerationContext context, Object target)
       at AutoPoco.Engine.ObjectBuilder.EnactActionsOnObject(IGenerationContext context, Object createdObject)
       at AutoPoco.Engine.ObjectBuilder.CreateObject(IGenerationContext context)
       at AutoPoco.Engine.ObjectGenerator`1.Get()
       at AutoPoco.Engine.CollectionContext`2.<Get>b__2(IObjectGenerator`1 x)
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
       at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
       at AutoPoco.Engine.CollectionContext`2.Get()

       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Constraint is that I can't change entities because they are generated by external tool.

So my quisetions are:

1. Is it possible to generate(using AutoPoco) list of projects where each of project contains collecion of `ProjectMembers`
2. Maybe there are better tools to generate data which will work with
   my entities?

I know that I can generate list of projects in a first place and next generate list of `ProjectMembers` then bind those collection together. But having everything configured in one place is really tempting.

**PS.** Main reasone why I choose `AutoPoco` was that it allows you really easly create new datasources like `FirstNameSource`, `ProjectTitleSource` etc.

Edit 1:
How AutoPoco extension for collection looks like: https://github.com/hvitorino/AutoPoco/blob/master/AutoPoco/StandardExtensions.cs

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you are trying to achieve is possible in configuration you have. In short: FromParent() has not been designed to be used as you are trying to use it. FromParent() would have worked, if you had following disposition:

```
class Project
{
  public int ProjectId {get;set;}
  public string Title { get; set; }
  public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
  public IList<ProjectMember> ProjectMembers { get; set; }
}

class ProjectMember
{
  public int ProjectId {get;set;}
  public bool isConfirmed { get; set; }
  public string ProjectPosition { get; set; }
}
```

In that situation FromParent() call on ProjectMember.ProjectId would have traverse generation context to the parent object and grabbed property with the same name an type on a Project object and your code would have worked. But, alas, it didn't come to pass.:)